# How to normalize blockchain storage?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am wondering how to model my assets, participants, transactions en events. I have already looked on documentation on how to do it syntax wise, but I was wondering if there is a structured way to do it. Just like the way normalization is done on relational databases.

If someone has principles about blockchain data storage, i would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperledger Fabric is based on key-value stores (LevelDB and CouchDB), so you don't really gain any benefit from normalizing data. In relational databases you do it for easy indexing and joins, but in key-value-stores there is no such thing as joins.

What you can do is create indexes on your data for faster querying. This is covered in the [Marbles tutorial chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/marbles02/node/marbles_chaincode.js) (l.108+):

```
let indexName = 'color~name'
let colorNameIndexKey = await stub.createCompositeKey(indexName, [marble.color, marble.name]);
```

For modeling your assets in Hyperledger Composer you can use [.cto definitions](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language).